# Add django form without refreshing the page using ajax

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms

I am trying to implement a django model-form to add a new item to the category table from add product form using html modal pop up and the code works fine. Here I want the model-form to work asynchronously without refreshing the page using javascript(ajax).

**The data is populated in db_table after submitting the ajax_form but it is not displayed in the html template until I refresh the page.** How can I do this?

> models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost_price = models.FloatField()
    sell_price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

> forms.py

```
class AddProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
class AddCategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```

> views.py

```
def add_product(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_form = AddProductForm(request.POST or None)

        if product_form.is_valid():
            product = product_form.save(commit=False)
            product.save()

            return redirect('add_product')
        else:
            return HttpResponse(product_form.errors)
    else:
        product_form = AddProductForm()
    return render(request,'add_product.html',{'product_form':product_form, 'categories':categories})

def ajax_add_category(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_form = AddCategoryForm(request.POST or None)
        if category_form.is_valid():
            category = category_form.save(commit=False)
            category.save()
            return redirect('add_product')
    else:
        category_form = AddCategoryForm()
    return render(request,'add_product.html',{'form':category_form})
```

> html template

```
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Name..." maxlength="200" required id="id">
    <label>Category</label>
    <div class="form-group">
                 <select name="category" class="form-control mr-3" style="width:50%; display:inline;" required id="id_category">
{% for category in categories %}


<option value="{{category.id}}">{{category.title}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
```

Add New Category

> html modal

```
<div class="modal" id="item-category-modal">
 <div class="modal-body">
  <form method="POST" data-url="{% url 'add-category' %}" id="category-ajax-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <p><label for="id_title">Title:</label> <input type="text" name="title"></p>
 <button class="btn btn-primary mt-30">Add Category</button>
  </form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

> javascript(ajax) code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $categoryForm = $('#category-ajax-form')
    $categoryForm.submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault()
      event.stopPropagation()
      var $formData = $(this).serialize()
var $thisURL = $categoryForm.attr('data-url') 
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: $thisURL,
data: $formData,
success: handleFormSuccess,
});
});

    function handleFormSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      $("#id_category").append(new Option(data.title, data.pk));

      $('#id_category').val(data.pk);
      $('#item-category-modal').modal('toggle');

// $categoryForm.reset(); // reset form data
}
});
</script>
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('add-category/', views.ajax_add_category, name='add-category'),
path('add/product/',views.add_product,name='add_product'),
    ]
```

Comment: Please check for errors in your browser console.

Comment: no errors in console and data is also populated in db_table. But the data shows only when page is refreshed in the template.

Comment: can you please share your urls.py file.

Comment: @chiragsoni edited

Comment: So basically new category is not getting displayed in the category list after adding the one through the ajax but getting populated in db right?

Comment: also, check in the console by doing `console.log(data)`  to make sure that you are getting the data from the backend.

Comment: @chiragsoni yeah new category is not being displayed in category list in html template but is populated in db.  I tried `console.log(data)` but not getting data from backend.

Comment: So first you try to get it from the backend then I will show you the trick to display it without the page reload.

Comment: @chiragsoni the data comes from the backend in the category list but only after the page refresh.

Comment: That you are getting because you are using `categories = Category.objects.all()` in your `add_product` view  What I am asking you is that after adding the category you open the google chrome developer console and check whether you are getting the data or not. So in `handleFormSuccess` fn use `console.log(data)`

Comment: See I am posting the detailed answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create new html template let say `ajaxCategories.html` and in this you add this code:

```
{% for category in categories %}
<option value="{{category.id}}">{{category.title}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Now in your existing html template remove this code and include it like this:

```
<select name="category" class="form-control mr-3" style="width:50%; display:inline;" 
   required id="id_category">
 {% include "ajaxCategories.html" %}
</select>
```

Note: while including use proper path then only it will be included.

Now in the ajax view do some changes like this:

```
def ajax_add_category(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_form = AddCategoryForm(request.POST or None)
        if category_form.is_valid():
            category = category_form.save(commit=False)
            category.save()
            #return redirect('add_product')
            categories = Category.objects.all()
    else:
        category_form = AddCategoryForm()
    return render(request,'ajaxCategories.html',{'categories':categories})
```

Now in the `handleFormSuccess` fn add this line of code:

```
$("#id_category").html(data)
```

With this new implementation the `data` you are getting in the ajax response is the entire html template that you will fit in the select tag.

Comment: feel free to ask any question.

Comment: Got to know what changes you need to do?

Comment: Not boasting by answering but to get good and good result make a habit of appreciating the people who answer your question even if you got a little idea from them. It is beneficial for you only.

Comment: sorry bro don't have enough reputations